# Inconsistency of Cap's shield

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, captain-america, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

In **Captain America: The Winter Soldier**, in the scene where Cap, Widow, and Falcon are ambushed on the highway by the Winter Soldier and his team of cronies at one point Captain America confronts one of the goons who is firing at him with a minigun.  Cap uses his shield to angle the ricocheting bullets at some of the other goons, taking them out.

However in **Captain America: The First Avenger**, when Agent Carter test fires her 1911 Colt .45 at his shield for the first time, the slugs simply mushroom and drop to the ground at his feet rather than ricochet.

Is this just an inconsistency on the writer's part, or did I miss something?

Comment: It could just be the angle of impact.

Comment: It might be a lower muzzle velocity, or a different type of bullet.

Comment: A bullet made of solid lead (as some practice rounds are) would be more likely to just deform on impact. Harder materials would ricochet.

Comment: All of these comments could be answers; comments aren't for answering the question, no matter how perfunctorily.

Comment: Since when? There are plenty of time people make comments which could be construed AS ANSWERS. Perhaps they aren't trying to put their suppositions in a role to be considered high quality answers.

Comment: @BESW Comments are often used to posit a theory when the user doesn't have time or doesn't care to spend time fleshing out a full answer

Comment: @BESW Comments on non-meta questions aren't for discussing meta issues, either. Oops, now I'm guilty, too.

Comment: On-topic(ish): I'm more concerned that Bucky's goons didn't think to aim their automatic weapons at Cap's feet. Just because the shield looks like a target, doesn't mean you have to aim for it, boys.

Comment: Literally no one ever aims at Cap's exposed head or feet. I always took it as an unwritten rule, given how fast his reflexes are, he'd be able to drop down behind the shield should that ever actually happen though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Apparently his shield, made from a rare metal called 'Vibranium' which absorbs and dissipates energy if directly impacted. This being the case, a bullet (typically comprised of a lead core inside a copper jacket, commonly called 'ball ammo') fired directly (90 degrees) at the shield surface would expend all it's energy into the shield surface, deforming the projectile but not rebounding because of the shield's energy absorption properties. But if the projectile were to impact the shield on a lesser angle, not all of it's energy would be transferred into the shield but rather be deflected at an angle, away from the shield. This is commonly called a ricochet.

Comment: You can also see that Cap lines it up carefully before it happens - he's planning the shot, and is actively trying to get the ricochet.  In the First Avenger, he was trying not to die as a matter of reflex.

Comment: Excellent answer. It's also correct; think of the difference between stabbing a shield, resulting in a bent knife, or hitting it with a glancing blow, which results in a parry.

Comment: This makes sense, it could also go so far as to explain how he can throw his shield and have it bounce of a target and return to him instead of dropping to the ground on impact.

Comment: @Monty129 There are some medieval offensive shield striking techniques that Cap. uses to great effect. Using the outer edge of the shield as a striking surface is actually quite devastating and could easily crush a human skull. Cap. has taken this shield fighting technique to the next level and often uses his shield as a ranged weapon. Because of the shields energy transferring properties and his exceptional strength, he can cause the thrown shield to actually rebound and ricochet off of targets when the shield edge strikes it. He's apparently very good at geometry too.

Comment: @Morgan I'd hate to play against him in pool.